# How to Hide MDI parent forms Control Box

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use Manual Close button in the parent form.
I disabled the Control Box,minimize box and set FormBorderStyle to none but
the mdiParent form still showing the Control box

Comment: I set `ControlBox` of my mdi parent form to false and it didn't show control box anymore. What's the problem?

Comment: Do you want to hide control box of your child window?

Comment: when i add a child control mdi parent forms  title bar shows @RezaAghaei

Comment: and i also want to hide my child forms control box

Comment: Share your code when you add child to mdi parent. and also you should know you can not hide child title bar simply, you may want take a look at [How to remove control box from MDIchild form](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32153316/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

solved it!!
I just added a menustrip in the mdi parent form and make visible=false
and make the parent formborderstyle=none to all mdi and child form

Answer (score 0):

Set the childForm's ControlBox property to false.