# How can I remove the double form title bar?

Tags: vb.net

I have a mdi container form that when it opens a child inside I get this double title bar with another set of close/minimize/maximize buttons and the form icon. How can I get rid of it? I've tried setting `Control` to `false` but it does not work. `FormBorderStyle` to `none` also does not work and it deforms the child form.

Also, I have a toolstrip that contains some buttons and it has this annoying border looking line at the bottom (check out the blue arrow I drew). How can I disable that aswell? [image]

Comment: That's how MDI works. The buttons allow the control of the child window within the parent. If you don't want that behavior, don't use MDI.

Comment: In the child Form Resize event, you can `BeginInvoke()` its MdiParent and remove the first items in its `MainMenuStrip` (after the child Form is maximized - that's why you need to `BeginInvoke()` -, the first MenuStrip Item is the Child Form SystemMenu icon). You won't see the Icon in far-left side anymore. The other buttons are better left where they are, but now the MenuStrip doesn't look like another TitleBar. Maybe it's enough.

Comment: Of course, in the Resize event, you need to check whether the Child Form `WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized`, otherwise you'll remove all the menus from the MdiParent's MenuStrip :)

Answer (score 0):

> **First Part**

---

For the first part of your question, the workaround posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32153316/10216583) by Mr. @RezaAghaei could be the answer. Here's the VB.NET version:

```vb
Public Class YourParentForm

    'Or drop one in the designer...
    Private ReadOnly ContainerPanel As Panel

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        IsMdiContainer = False
        ContainerPanel = New Panel With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
        Controls.Add(ContainerPanel)
    End Sub

End Class
```

And where you create the child Form:

```vb
Dim f As New ChildForm With
    {
    .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
    .TopLevel = False,
    .ControlBox = False,
    .Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    }
ContainerPanel.Controls.Add(f)
f.Show()
```

Since the last inserted control into the collection is docked first, you need to explicitly set the order of the controls to avoid any possible dock overlapping. So as you noticed and mentioned in your comment, the `Dock.Fill` Form is overlapping the `Dock.Top` Label. To fix that:

```vb
Dim f As New ChildForm With
{
.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
.TopLevel = False,
.ControlBox = False,
.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
}
ContainerPanel.Controls.Add(f)
Controls.SetChildIndex(ContainerPanel, 0)
Controls.SetChildIndex(Label1, 1)
f.Show()
```

In fact you can omit `Controls.SetChildIndex(Label1, 1)`, just added to clear up the idea.

If you'r using the designer to add the `ContainerPanel`, select it and right click, you will see in the context menu `Bring to Front` and `Send to Back` which are used to do the same thing. Also, you can use the **Document Outline** window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> to show it) to change the order of the controls using the up/down arrows and the left/right arrows to move controls to different containers.

> **Second Part**

---

As for the second part, you need to create a new class that inherits the [ProfessionalColorTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.professionalcolortable?view=netframework-4.8) and override the [ToolStripBorder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.professionalcolortable.toolstripborder?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ProfessionalColorTable_ToolStripBorder) property to prevent it from returning the default color when rendering the ToolStrip:

```vb
Public Class CustomColorTable
    Inherits ProfessionalColorTable

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ToolStripBorder As Color
        Get
            Return Color.Empty
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Then, pass the custom color table to a new instance of the [ToolStripProfessionalRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer?view=netframework-4.8) class and assign it to the [ToolStrip.Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.renderer?view=netframework-4.8) or the [ToolStripManager.Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmanager.renderer?view=netframework-4.8) properties.

Revisiting the constructor of the parent Form:

```vb
Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    ContainerPanel = New Panel With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
    Controls.Add(ContainerPanel)

    ToolStrip1.Renderer = New ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(New CustomColorTable) With {
        .RoundedEdges = False
    }

    'Or
    'ToolStripManager.Renderer = New ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(New CustomColorTable) With {
    '    .RoundedEdges = False
    '}
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank for the reply! To the first part of the question: the solution you gave me works. The title bar disappears but the label you can see in my picture (under the buttons, where it says 'Crear client') becomes hidden, the toolstrip overlays it. Do you know how could I fix that?